# SQL to LINQ Extensions Methods (with aggregate function)

Tags: sql, linq, aggregate

First I want to thank the people who take the time to help me.
Going to the example, imagining that I have the following tables in my DB.

```
------------
tPerson
____________
ID | AGE | countryID


------------
tPet
____________
ID | personID


-----------
tCountry
___________
ID | Name
```

**I was wondering how can I write next query with LINQ (but *with extension methods*)**

```
SELECT tCountry.ID, tCountryName,
    SUM(CASE WHEN(tPeople.Age <20 && subQ.hasPets = 0) THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS first,
    SUM(CASE WHEN(tPeople IN (20,21,22,23,24,25) && subQ.hasPets > 0) THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS second,
    SUM(CASE WHEN(tPeople.Age > 25) THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS third
FROM tPeople
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT tPeople.ID, COUNT(tPet.ID) AS hasPets
    FROM tPeople INNER JOIN tPet ON tPet.PersonID = tPeople.ID
    GROUPBY tPeopleID
) AS subQ
ON subQ.ID = tPeople.ID
LEFT JOIN tCountry ON tPeople.countryID = tCountry.ID WHERE tCountry.ID = XX
GROUP BY (tCountry.ID, tCountryName)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you mean to use `Window Functions()` and `Sql.Ext.` the first, please change your SQL Query and use window function() in it

Answer (score 0):

```
var subQuery = from tPeople in People
           join tPet in Pet on tPeople.Id equals tPet.PersonId
           group tPeople by tPeople.Id into g
           select new { Id = g.Key, hasPets = g.Count() };

var mainQuery = from tPeopel in People
                join _subQ in subQuery on tPeopel.Id equals _subQ.Id into _subQLeft
                from subQ in _subQLeft.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join _tCuntry in Country on tPeopel.CountryId equals _tCuntry.Id into _tCountryLeft
                from tCountry in _tCountryLeft.DefaultIfEmpty()     
                select new
                {
                    Id = tPeopel.Id,
                    Age = tPeopel.Age,
                    HasPets= subQ.hasPets,
                    CountryId = tCountry.Id,
                    CountryName = tCountry.Name
                };

var Finalquery = from mainQ in mainQuery
            where mainQ.CountryId == 55
            group mainQ by new { mainQ.CountryId, mainQ.CountryName } into g
            select new
            {
                CountryId = g.Key.CountryId,
                CountyName = g.Key.CountryName,
                First = g.Sum(t => (t.Age < 20 && t.HasPets == 1) ? 1 : 0),
                Second = g.Sum(t => (new int[] { 20, 21, 23, 24, 25 }.Contains(t.Id) && t.HasPets > 0) ? 1 : 0),
                Third = g.Sum(t => t.Age > 25 ? 1 : 0)
            };

var result = await Finalquery.ToListAsync();
```

I separated them for more readability and better understanding

But if you ask me, I suggest you use `Raw SQL Query` or `Dapper` for this situation

Because it's simple and more optimal and faster in my opinion

And, as far as I know, it doesn't produce an optimal SQL query when Linq query(to SQL) be complex

If you mean to use `Window Functions()` and `Sql.Ext.`, I think about this situation
it is not very useful, but if you want, first, please change your `SQL Query` and use `window function()` in it

Comment: Hi Hesam, thanks for your reply, but I'm not just looking for LINQ in SQL representation. I want to learn how do it with LINQ "Extension methods"(for example .Include() .Where() .GroupBy(), etc... Is it the corret name "Extension methods"?) how you can check on the title of the question. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: I'm so busy right now, but I'll do it as soon as I can.

Just that, `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` has kinds of Extention like: `DbFunctionsExtensions`,`EntityTypeExtensions`, `EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions (Include,AsNoTracking, AllAsync,FirstAsync,...)`,etc.

I suggest you visit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions?view=efcore-3.1 to learn about it